# multi AntiForgeryToken does not work on Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, internet-explorer, web, owasp

The issue is that my `<form>` does not work on Internet Explorer but it works fine in Chrome.

With this code Internet explorer shows that   'This page could not be loaded'

```
<form id="removeRequestorRoleForm" action="~/Admin/RemoveRole" method="post">
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      <input type="hidden" id="userId" name="userId" value="@item.Id" />
      <input type="hidden" id="role" name="role" value="Requestor" />
      <input type="submit" value="Remove" onclick="removeRole()" style="background:none; border:0; color:#0000EE; text-decoration:underline" />   
</form>
```

But when the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is commented, the page works fine in IE and Chrome.

Is there any limit for the tokens? Maybe something is wrong with the token generation.